# How to automatically create `.html` pages and routes as an Admin using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask framework to create a web application which is a platform for students to study various STEM related subjects. The study contents to view for students is only released by the Admin of the web app.

I was wondering if there is a way for the Admin to create new subjects when logged in. When creating a new subject, is there a way to automatically update the templates file with the new subject, alongside with adding the new subjects route.

I hope I've made my explanation easy to understand. Also, bare in mind, I am a beginner in using Flask, and Python in general.

Comment: I would advise checking out Django instead of Flask. It includes out-of-the-box admin functionality, which can also be customised where you need to.

Comment: I am using Flask as this is a University project I am currently assigned to. So I am seeking for a solution to implement within the Flask framework.

Comment: [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is similar to the out-of-the-box admin functionality Robin mentioned, if that helps. The Github repo also has some nice examples of how you might use it.